# When will it take for online flight search engines to include NewLeaf (new Canadian discount airline)?

Tags: air-travel, canada, flight-search-engines

In no wise am I connected with, or employed by, [Newleaf](http://www.cbc.ca/news/business/newleaf-airline-launch-1.3648772), a new discount airline serving only Canadian cities that will commence service on 2016/7/25.

My grandparents wish to book flights with Newleaf, but must first consult  online flight search engines (e.g. Skyscanner or Matrix), especially if they must also take other airlines for airports that NewLeaf does not service.

Comment: I guess they will wait until they get off the ground, at min. If I were an online flight search engine, i wouldn't want to get sued over tickets I sold that get cancelled.

Comment: @ OP +1 but please edit your question a bit to clarify that Newleaf is a new airline in Canada. @ Close-voters did you read the Q and look to the link? There is nothing unclear or opinion-based about this! At best it is hard to say, but this is hardly a reason to close this nice Q!

Comment: @mts I've read the question but I don't understand OP's travel-related problem. Do they want to book tickets on Newleaf?

Comment: They want to know when they will be able to search for those e.g. on skyscanner or expedia or matrix. I think it is travel-related, because as a budget traveler you should be aware of what airlines are featured on which online-flight search engine, like knowing that Ryanair is not on matrix or Southwest nowhere apparently. @JonathanReez

Comment: @mts The question of "Is NewLeaf on Search Engines?" is answerable. The question of "When is it going to be on Search Engines?" is impossible to predict and therefore not answerable.

Comment: @JonathanReez I agree but that does not make it a close reason, one can answer as you say that this is not predictable and depends on company policy. We have had [similarly unanswerable questions by respected users here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/69617/32134) in this aspect and I see no reason to close.

Comment: @mts +1. Thank you for your support. I have edited my post; but please feel free to edit it if I have not done enough.

Comment: Why not check on Skyscanner first and then try NewLeaf's official site?

Comment: @JonathanReez I am hoping to combine flight routes with NewLeaf and other airlines, particularly if NewLeaf does not fly to a specific airport.

Comment: @Aganju A search engine is not the same thing as a seller, although some do both.

Comment: Edited the title, because the title read like (to me) "How long until search engines stop showing NewLeaf flights"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like many other low-cost air carriers, you cannot search flights or book tickets on NewLeaf through online flight search engines or booking sites.

NewLeaf have this to say on their [About Us](http://gonewleaf.ca/about/) page:

> **Remember www.GoNewLeaf.ca** because we’re not using any booking sites. To keep costs down, we sell directly to the customer and a small number of exclusive partners.

(Those partners are not named, and that information doesn't appear to be available yet.)

Comment: Note that Kayak *can* search all of Europe's low-costs, and I presume it will be able to search NewLeaf soon.

Comment: Also note that you can search for alternatives on a search site and compare the results with the price one airline offers on its own site.

Comment: @JonathanReez Only if NewLeaf allows it, and this is not guaranteed.